# Removing ArrayList object duplicates and getting sum of value

Tags: java, arraylist, comparison

I have a list of a certain type of Object. I need to remove the duplicates object key field and sum up their values. It's kinda hard to explain so let me show you an example.

Say you have an Item class:

```
public class Item {

protected String name;

protected int quantity;

public String getName() {
    return name;
   }

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
   }

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
   }

public void setQuantity(intquantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
   }

}
```

And you have a list of Item's:

```
List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

Populated as:

```
 Item item1 = new Item();
 item1.setName("mice");
 item1.setQuantity(20);

 Item item2 = new Item();
 item2.setName("keyboards");
 item2.setQuantity(30);


 Item item3 = new Item();
 item3.setName("monitors");
 item3.setQuantity(4);

 Item item4 = new Item();
 item4.setName("mice");
 item4.setQuantity(15);

 Item item5 = new Item();
 item5.setName("cables");
 item5.setQuantity(50);


 itemList.add(0, item1);
 itemList.add(1, item2);
 itemList.add(2, item3);
 itemList.add(3, item4);
 itemList.add(4, item5);
```

I need to have an output ArrayList that doesn't have duplicates, and adds up the quantity value.

So essentially, the result should be an arraylist of elements: mice, keyboards, monitors, cables where mice quantity = 35 (the sum), the keyboards quantity = 30, monitors = 4, cables = 50.

Comment: Please show your attempt at solving this problem and what went wrong.  This looks like it would be easy in an RDBMS - it would be a group-by query with a "sum" aggregate function.

Comment: Not asking for the complete answer, I just need help with the logic -

Answer (score 5):

Provided you are using Java 8, you can use [Collectors#groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```
itemList.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getName, Collectors.summingInt(Item::getQuantity)));
```

Comment: This looks like what I need (group by).. but I am not using Java 8 :(

Comment: One more reason to upgrade :)

Answer (score 2):

use a HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> myItemMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
if(myItemMap.containsKey(item)
{
  int currentQty = myItemMap.get(item);
  myItemMap.get(item).setQuantity(qty + currentQty )
}
else
{
  myItemMap.put(item, qty);
}
```

Comment: Giving this a shot now. My initial assumption was to convert to hashmap. thanks ill let you know

Comment: you can also use an ArrayList if you want to keep using your Item object, let me tweak my answer